# Prevent previously loaded entity being updated in transactional method

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have the following method in one of my services

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void createUserInfo(long userId, UserInfo userInfo) {
     User oldUser = userService.findUserById(userId);

     if (oldUser.infoIsTheSame(userInfo)) {
         return;
     }

     User updatedUser = userService.addUserInfo(userId, userInfo);      
     feedService.addFeed(FeedAction.INFO_UPDATE, oldUser, updatedUser);               
}
```

As you can see `findUserById()` and `addUserInfo()` methods are in the same service, which is marked as `@Transactional` itself.

As the `userService.findUserById()` executes in the same transaction that `createUserInfo()` started, the `oldUser` instance is also affected by the change of user info inside `addUserInfo()` (as the loaded managed entity is in the same transaction).

So my problem is when trying to `addFeed()` the `oldUser` and `updatedUser` are the same after the service method calls.

So my question is if there is a way to change so that `oldUser` will not be affected?

Note that changing `addUserInfo()` to start new transaction is not an option for me, as it is used in several other places.

I tried also to copy the `oldUser` (e.g. via [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/)) but the issue stays.

Thnx for help.

Comment: You can try to detach `oldUser` from session. If you're using Hibernate - `session.evict()`, with JPA 2.0 - `entityManager.detach()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`EntityManager.detach()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach%28java.lang.Object%29), to detach the entity from the persistence context:

```
User oldUser = userService.findUserById(userId);

if (oldUser.infoIsTheSame(userInfo)) {
    return;
}

em.detach(oldUser); 
User updatedUser = userService.addUserInfo(userId, userInfo);      
feedService.addFeed(FeedAction.INFO_UPDATE, oldUser, updatedUser);
```